# How to use the select2 option in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I am working in asp.net core. I am using typescript. I want to use the Select2. How to use the select2 in asp.net core? Is there any package want to install for using select2?

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party, but had the same problem.

My needs were to add a select2-multiselector, where the data was loaded via ajax. So possibly you need to change a bit.

You can add this js and css:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

My View (the model is an `IEnumerable`):

```html
...
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
{
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[index].Id"/>
        <input type="text" asp-for="@Model[index].Title">

        <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" style="width: 100%;" asp-for="@Model[index].TagIds" multiple="multiple">
            @foreach (TagDetailModel tag in Model[index].Tags)
            {
                <option value="@tag.Id" selected="selected">@tag.Name</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
}
...
```

What I did:
Added a `select` in the view, gave it a class where I can access it later with javascript. If you need to add multiple values, you add `multiple="multiple"`
In my model I added the tags that already were assigned to the model. They aren't automatically added with select2, you need to add them yourself. If you don't have multiple enabled, your `Tags` is probably just one `Tag` and you don't need to enumerate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
    ajax: {
            url: '/Tag/GetTags',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "GET",
            quietMillis: 50,
            data: function (term) {
                return {
                    term: term
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            text: item.name,
                            id: item.id
                        }
                    })
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In this script, when the document loaded completely, I run the `select` as `select2`, simply with `$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2()`. I wanted to let select2 load the option via ajax (therefore the `ajax` property) - if you don't want to use ajax, you can add the possible values like in the view with just `<option value="@tag.Id">@tag.Name</option>`.

In my controller (`ImageController.cs` in my app) I just added a function for the ajax-request:

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> Tags(int id)
{
    return Json(await _imageService.Get(id));
}
```